# Comment editing grace period before edit-counter starts (pencil)

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, grace-period

I know there's already a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155497/comment-editing-grace-period). But things have changed recently since now you can even see how many times someone has edited his comment.

Maybe it is not best-practise, but i often post my first idea as  comment. So either something that might help OP to find the reason for his issue or how he can improve his question. Then, few seconds later, i recognize details and i'm editing my comment. Then i recognize typos and i'm going to correct them and so on.

So sometimes i've edited my comment multiple times in the five minutes.   I'm not a native English speaker, so i need more time to write and correct my comments. I feel treated like a schoolboy with   bad marks shown publicly.

So why not at least provide a grace period for comments and the edit-counter increases not until the period has expired?

Here's a screenshot from the pencil i mean:

[image]

Comment: What problem would this solve? Why is showing edits accurately a problem?

Comment: Who thinks an edited comment "shames" a user? Thats madness

Comment: @RichardTingle: Just an example for a different feature that was made invisible because it "shames" user, there's no relation.

Comment: No point in this in my opinion, I would just get rid of the pencil altogether as we don't have any way to see comment revisions anyway.

Comment: @shawizdoward11: i would prefer to remove the edit-count also. But since it was introduced recently I assume that this is not desired. But you can understand this question as vote against the pencil in general, at least the number.

Comment: @Richard: or is the tooltip with the number of edits not new at all and I have just recognized it recently?

Comment: @Tim it's not new, exists for at least couple of years most likely more.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: then my request could be closed since it is somewhat pointless because I didn't mind so far.  I could have sworn that it was relatively new.

Comment: @Tim no worry, happens to me many times too. Let's leave it be, can't see real reason to close this. (you can of course ask to delete it by flagging as Other if you like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really love ducks - `JDB`
>
> @JDB - I completely agree! - `DuckLover`

... 1 minute later ...

> I really hate ducks - `JDB` <sub>this comment was edited 1 time</sub>
>
> @JDB - I completely agree! - `DuckLover`
>
> @JDB - I hate them too! - `I Hate Poopy Grass`

... 1 minute later ...

> I really hate n00bs - `JDB` <sub>this comment was edited 2 times</sub>
>
> @JDB - I completely agree! - `DuckLover`
>
> @JDB - I hate them too! - `I Hate Poopy Grass`

Comment: Since you have no visible comment history you don't know the original comment anyway. Maybe it was "love  dugs" first then "love ducks", who knows? So the number of edits tells you nothing.

Comment: It does show you that it *has* been edited though.

Comment: @Flyk: but there was already the pencil that showed you that a comment was edited, the tooltip which now shows the number of edits is new. It is sufficient to know that a comment was edited.

Comment: @Flyk: never mind, I could have sworn that the tooltip with the number of edits was relatively new but apparently it is not. Then my whole question is pointless.